# AsyncTask, handle result in onPostExecute vs get()

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I would like to handle a return result from an `AsyncTask` outside of the class.

Is there any downside using, for example, `Location loc = TheClass.execute().get();`? 
Should I handle the result in `onPostExecute` inside the class instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get()
```

The purpose, of get(), is to block until the result is obtained. This
could be useful, for example, if you have multiple tasks, where one uses
another. One task could start another and call get() to wait for it to
finish before continuing with its own work.

```
onPostExecute (Result result)
```

Runs on the UI thread after doInBackground(Params...). The specified result is the value returned by doInBackground(Params...).

This method won't be invoked if the task was cancelled.

Answer (score 2):

The get() method is not well method for it, cause it stoped UI-thread

Answer (score 1):

The only place where you can be assured that the operation you have started in `doInBackground()` has completed is the callback method `onPostExecute()`. So using a get() is not such a wise idea as far as `AsyncTask` is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

get() make you (current Thread) wait until the result come and onPostExecute did work Asynchronously and work like a call back when the background work has been completed.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29)

public final Result get ()

Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Comment: Ok, so in other workds, using get() will make a synchronous call?